# Ag grid node.setSelected(true) does not display selected checkbox on UI

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I have an ag-grid table in which I have to select checkbox based on certain conditions after the data in the grid is loaded. I used `processRowPostCreate` as it allows to process rows after they are created. I used `node.setSelected(true)` to update the value. I did console.log to see node.selected value and I see the value is true. But, still the UI is not showing selected checkbox.

Below is the grid option and `processRowPostCreate` callback:

```
var dataTableOptions = {
    columnDefs: dataTableColDefn,
    suppressMovableColumns: true,
    rowSelection: 'multiple',
    rowMultiSelectWithClick: true,
    deltaRowDataMode: true,
    floatingFilter: false,  
    rowModelType: 'infinite',
    rowDragManaged: true,
    maxConcurrentDatasourceRequests: 1,
    maxBlocksInCache:1,
    cacheBlockSize: 25,
    pagination: true,
    paginationPageSize: 25,
    onRowClicked: function(event) { 
        resetRowVal(event);=
    },
    components: { 
        'cgStateCellRenderer': CgStateCellRenderer,
    },
    processRowPostCreate: (params) => {
        if(params.rowIndex > 0){
            params.node.setSelected(true); 
        }
        console.log(params);
    }
};
```

It works fine if I add `setTimeout` in `processRowPostCreate` callback. But it is not a good solution to handle this problem.

```
processRowPostCreate: (params) => {
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            if(params.rowIndex > 0){
                params.node.setSelected(true); 
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this did the trick :

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.grid.api.forEachNode((node) => {
    node.setSelected(isSelected);
  });
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used `processRowPostCreate`, so I can't comment on that directly, but I find that it is fairly common with AgGrid callbacks that if you are calling grid APIs in the callback, you have to do a `setTimeout` to ensure that your api call happens after the current JavaScript processing loop, and that if you don't do this, the grid may behave in unexpected ways, or simply seem to ignore your api call.

That said, you generally should not have to provide a timeout delay - the default value of zero should get you to the next iteration of the processing loop.

In fact, it would be unreliable to set a value other that zero for the delay, as you cannot predict the processing speed of the client that is running your application.

So, I suggest replacing

```
processRowPostCreate: (params) => {
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            if(params.rowIndex > 0){
                params.node.setSelected(true); 
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
```

with

```
processRowPostCreate: (params) => {
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            if(params.rowIndex > 0){
                params.node.setSelected(true); 
            }
        });
    }
```

and if that works consistently, then that's probably the best solution.

If it doesn't work, you might try creating a list of rowIds to be selected, 
and calling the `setSelected` method on each item in the list at a later time,
if you can find a predictable way to do that without resorting to a specified time delay (such as in response to another, later event if an appropriate one exists).

Comment: Thanks, @GreyBeardedGeek! I tried setTimeout with no timeout delay but still, it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?